# How to transform: translatex(0%) when click event using react

Tags: css, reactjs, transform

I am new to react and tring to build mobile responsive navbar. in mobile view i want to slide the navbar and I added click event to change transform : translateX(0%) but css doesn't appear to work.  here's how my code looks like.

App.js

```
import Navbar from "./components/Navbar";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Navbar />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Navbar.jsx

```
import '../css/navbar.css'
import {useState} from 'react';

function Navbar() {
  
  const [isShowNavLinks, setIsShowNavLinks] = useState(false);

  const handleBurgerClick = () => {
    setIsShowNavLinks(!isShowNavLinks)
    console.log(isShowNavLinks)
  }

  return (
    <nav className="nav">
      <h2 className='logo'>LOGO</h2>
      <div className="burger" onClick={handleBurgerClick}>
        <div className="line1"></div>
        <div className="line2"></div>
        <div className="line3"></div>
      </div>
      <ul className={isShowNavLinks? 'nav-active' : ''}>
        <li>Home</li>
        <li>About</li>
        <li>Contact</li>
        <li>Blog</li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  )
}

export default Navbar;
```

navbar.css

```
.nav{
  background-color: #16003B;
  color: #EEEEEE;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  height: 10vh;
}

.logo {
  padding: 1%;
}

.nav ul {
  width: 60vw;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  list-style: none;
}

ul li {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.burger {
  display: none;
}

.burger>div {
  width: 25px;
  height: 2px;
  background-color:white;
  margin: 4px;
}

@media  screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  body{
    overflow-x: hidden;
  }
  .burger {
    display: block;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  .nav ul{
    position:absolute;
    top:10vh;
    right:0px;
    width:50%;
    height:90vh;
    background-color: #16003B;
    flex-direction: column;
    transform: translateX(100%);
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    align-items: center;
    transition: 0.5s ease-in;
  }
  .nav-active {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
  
}
```

when click on .burger in dom it shows nav-active class but doesn't apply the its css

[DOM when click burger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/no92r.png)

Comment: there has a package to do this type of stuff. you can look over it https://reactcommunity.org/react-transition-group/

Comment: Will be great if you share a sandbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> just simply add the !important property on the nav-active class because it will give high priority to this class.
> To read out more about it go to this link [about important property in css](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_important.asp)

[After adding important property it will work fine for me. Go to checkout](https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-silence-o3w9o8?file=/src/css/navbar.css)

```
.nav-active{
 transform:translateX(0) !important;
}
```

Comment: Please vote up my answer if worked and click to tick the check mark in my Answer it will be helpful for both of us.